# Webservice REST não retorna o XML no IIS 8.0

Tags: web-service, iis, restful

O webservice no visual studio 2013 funciona lindamente. Adicionei-o ao IIS do windows 8.1, e ele quando chega altura de enviar os dados via REST, dá-me este erro:

> O servidor encontrou um erro ao processar o pedido. Consulte a página de ajuda do serviço para construir pedidos válidos para o serviço.

Metodo: GET

WebConfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BD_Super_V8ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=NUNO-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BD_Super_V8;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <!-- REST -->
    <services>
      <service name="WcfServicePedido_v7.ServicePedido">
        <endpoint name="RestEndPoint"
                  contract="WcfServicePedido_v7.IServicePedido"
                  binding="webHttpBinding"
                  address=""
                  behaviorConfiguration="restBehavior" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="restBehavior">
          <webHttp helpEnabled="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <!-- REST -->
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Serviço:
    [ServiceContract]

```
public interface IServicePedido
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Retorna todos os pedidos (JSON)
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "maquinas/?volta={volta}",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    [OperationContract]
    List<VoltaPDA> GetAllMaquinasVolta(int volta);
}
```

Apaguei e voltei a publicar o WebService:
Agora dá me este erro:

> The server encountered an error processing the request. Please see the
>   service help page for constructing valid requests to the service.
>
> LOG FILE:

```
2014-03-07 10:53:43 ::1 GET /ServicePedido.svc/help - 8095 - ::1
 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/33.0.1750.146+Safari/537.36
 http://localhost:8095/ServicePedido.svc/maquinas/?volta=1 200 0 0 24
```

Comment: Não é possível extrair uma mensagem de erro mais detalhada? Veja por favor se o erro não é um 404, mesmo que para uma rota válida

Comment: Você está trabalhando com requisições POST?

Comment: Estou trabalhando em um ambiente similar ao seu é esse tipo de problema é sempre oriundo de falta de configuração no ISS, ou alguma permissão, problemas relacionados a isso. E como o @Tiago mencionou é possível obter mais detalhes do erro? Para poder te ajudar?

Comment: o método que utilizo é com requisições GET. O único erro que me fornece é o que mencionei em cima. Também penso que o erro será das configurações do IIS.

Comment: Como voce envia os dados via REST? Um cliente? Poste o código. Uma requisição POST? GET? Poste a requisicao. Cabeçalhos enviados, Content-type, Accept, detalhes do log do erro, o application.wadl com o trecho relevante. É muito difícil ajudar sem ter informações suficientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aparentemente seu WCF roda e o erro ocorre em runtime. O primeiro passo é tentar alterar a mensagem de erro, para algo mais específico e assim ter condições de localizar o problema. Verifique se você tem o debug habilitado no arquivo .svc

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" ... %>
```

Em seguida no arquivo .config mude essa opção para true

```
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
```

Ainda pode ser necessário habilitar o wcf tracing para ir mais a fundo, segue um artigo que ajuda com isso: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx

Tente fazer o seguinte também:

- No IIS em Pools de Aplicativos
- Selecione aquele que o seu WCF está utilizando
- Clique o botão direito e vá em Configurações Avançadas
- Identidade, mude para NetworkService

Answer (score 0):

> O servidor encontrou um erro ao processar o pedido. Consulte a página
>   de ajuda do serviço para construir pedidos válidos para o serviço. A
>   mensagem de exceção é 'Cannot open database "BD_Super_V8" requested by
>   the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS
>   APPPOOL\WebService'.'. Consulte os registos do servidor para obter
>   mais detalhes. O rastreio da pilha de exceções é:
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlConnectionManager.UseConnection(IConnectionUser
>   user) at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.get_IsSqlCe() at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.InitializeProviderMode() at
>   System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression
>   query) at
>   System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()
>   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source) at
>   SyncInvokeGetAllMaquinasVolta(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc) at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Este foi erro que retornou graças a sua ajuda Iuristona, mas continua a não entender o porquê de não conseguir fazer o login na base de dados, quando no visual studio funciona lindamente. Tem haver com permissões?

Comment: vou editar minha resposta anterior, para acrescentar uma tentativa de solução

Answer (score 0):

cara eu sou novo nesse negocio de webServer mas pelo que eu vi o seu método recebe um argumento como parâmetro. não sei se estou falando besteira mas pelo que entendi quando estava estudando isso só pode ser feito via Post e o como você mesmo mencionou ele envia via Get. E na verdade conceitualmente esse é a forma mais segura.